# Socket connection using perl UserAgent

Tags: perl, proxy, websocket

I have a script which uses following code to connect to a server.

```
$sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
                                  PeerAddr => $server,
                                  PeerPort => $port,
                                  Proto => 'tcp',
                                );
```

However, I am behind a proxy server and can not use this script. To overcome this, I have to add proxy support. A suggestion on SO was to use `UserAgent`. Since I am a Perl illiterate, I am not sure how to replace this code with the one which uses `UserAgent`. I don't want to touch rest of the code. Can I redefine `$sock` using `UserAgent` so that script work file. The script I am talking about is available [here](http://moss.stanford.edu/general/scripts.html)

Comment: Hey do you have any solution now?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "UserAgent" module you're referring to.  There isn't a module named that.  There are lots of modules with UserAgent as part of the name, but I don't know of any that apply to your situation.

Anyway, I think you're looking for [IO::Socket::Socks](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aSocks).  I've never tried it myself, but you should be able to do:

```
use IO::Socket::Socks;

my $sock = IO::Socket::Socks->new(
  ProxyAddr   => $hostname_of_your_proxy,
  ProxyPort   => $port_number_your_proxy_listens_on,
  ConnectAddr => $server,
  ConnectPort => $port,
);
```

and leave the rest of the code as-is.

Comment: Do I have to worry about username and password for proxy authentication? Also ping command does not get any response from `moss.stanford.edu`. When I run your solution, it says `Could not connect to server moss.stanford.edu: Illegal seek`

Comment: If your proxy requires authentication, then yes, you'll need to supply the `Username` and `Password` attributes also (and maybe `AuthType` too, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were referring to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746614/use-proxy-with-perl-script)? But there's a difference between getting some files from HTTP server remotely (for this LWP::UserAgent is more relevant indeed) and submitting files via IO::Socket(::INET), as in the script you've linked.

You may use the great solution cjm offered, or just use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/), like that:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9999 TCP4:moss.stanford.edu:7690
```

...where 9999 refers to the local proxy port. The good: you won't have to change the moss' script; the bad: you'd have to install socat first.

Comment: You're right; that's probably the discussion he was talking about.  But LWP::UserAgent is useless for this purpose, because the script he's talking about uses a custom protocol, not HTTP or anything else LWP implements.

Comment: Yes. This is the discussion I read. Should have mentioned it. Thanks for this. I'll try this at this weekend.